# How does OKTA use SCIM for different user types?

Tags: okta, scim

I am implementing a SCIM server to integrate OKTA with my application. In my application I have two different types of users. What's the best way of handling this in OKTA?

Having looked at the SCIM v2 [core schema RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643) I think there are a couple of possibilities:

- Use "groups"
- Use "roles"
- Use "entitlements"

Which of these (if any) is the best way to implement this feature? Which features are supported by OKTA? And how do you configure these within OKTA?

Comment: My requirement is also same as yours. Wanted to know how did you solve your problem ? I do not see any libraries provided by spring boot for SCIM. So, should I just consider it as implementing REST APIs on my own ?

Answer (score 0):

Okta supports provisioning to both SCIM 1.1 and SCIM 2.0 APIs.

SCIM 2.0 implements OAuth 2.0 for access control. Okta supports:

- OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant Flow
- Basic Authentication
- Custom HTTP Header

Which of these (if any) is the best way to implement this feature?

-->Use a SCIM Library like [SCIM 2 SDK for Java](https://developer.unboundid.com/6.1.0.0/broker/guides/broker-client-developer-guide/resources/scim2-sdk-for-java/)

Which [features are supported by OKTA](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/index)?

- Create Users
- Read Users and Groups
- Update Users
- Deprovision (Deactivate) Users
- Sync Password

And how do you configure these within OKTA?
--> Please elaborate on what "These" are?

How can you the User/Group objects I can use to implement multiple user "types"?
Different User Types are Just [Different SCIM Resources](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SCIM%20Resource).

You could differentiate user by Group Membership or OAUth 2.0 Scopes.

Comment: To be clear, the issue I have does not relate to the SCIM protocol or which version is supported but which features of the User/Group objects I can use to implement multiple user "types".

Comment: I know I can define new resource types (in the same way enterprise user is an extension of user). But, assuming OKTA is the master repository in this scenario, my app won't be creating the users. Instead OKTA will create the users and push them to my app. In this scenario how should I map the OKTA users to users of my app? More specifically how do I know which user type to create for a given OKTA user?

Comment: Frankly, I am lost as to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Here is a simple example: My app has two types of user accounts call them "Consumers" and "Supervisors". Now consider the following: 1) an administrator, using the OKTA admin portal creates a new user. 2) the new user is pushed to my app via the SCIM Create User endpoint. 3) On receiving the user should I create a "Consumer" or "Supervisor"?